# Bitwise switch most significant and least significant bytes

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

Say I have a buffer which stores 2 bytes:

```
char *buf=new char[4];
// 00000010 00000000 (.. other stuff ..)
```

What I want to do is switching the least with the most significant byte, and store that value in a variable. Trying to do so as follows:

```
short len=buf[1];
len <<= 8;
len |= buf[0];
    // Result, as expected: 00000000 00000010
```

It works fines, UNLESS the most significant byte (buf[0]) is >= 128, which makes the or operator (|) fill half of the short with 1's. Example:

```
Original: 10000110 00000000
Should be: 00000000 10000110
But is: 11111111 10000110
```

Thanks (oh, I'm reading the bytes from a file with file.read(...,4); - don't even know anymore if this is relevant)

Comment: If you want to manipulate bits, use unsigned types. If you want to manipulate numbers, use signed types.

Comment: You could try std::bitset if you are new to bitwise operations. If lets you use bits like an array. You can convert back to an integer when you are done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your implementation obviously uses [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation of signed numbers. Use unsigned values instead

```
unsigned char * buf = new unsigned char[2];
...

unsigned short len=buf[1];
len <<= 8;
len |= buf[0];
```

Comment: +1
Armen is right. You actually performed and arithmetic instead of a logic shift. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts)... :D

Comment: That won't help if `char` is signed; `buf[0]` will still be sign-extended when it's promoted to `int` for `|=`. You need to change the type of `buf`, not `len`, to prevent the sign extension.

Comment: I have heard of right shift doing sign extension, but not left shift.

Comment: @brianbeuning: It's not the shift that does it; it's the promotion from `[signed] char` to `int`, which is needed to use `buf[0]` as an operand of `|=`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
unsigned short buf;
...
buf = buf << 8 | buf >> 8;
```

Or just perform a permutation:

```
char buf[2];
char tmp;
...
tmp = buf[0];
buf[0] = buf[1];
buf[1] = tmp;
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
 buff = 11001010 01011100;
 //copy this buff, I am writing it directly below  

 copy_of_buff = 11001010 01011100;  
 buff_hi = (buff >> 8);  //Hence after this exec, buff_hi = 00000000 11001010  
 buff_lo = (copy_of_buff << 8); //Hence after this exec, buff_lo = 01011100 00000000

 out_buff = (buff_hi)||(buff_lo); //Hence after this exec, out_buff = 01011100 11001010
```